# webpack 5 in storybook project is not building output files

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack, storybook

I have upgraded a storybook project from 5.1.8 to 6.5.16. We have our own components in the project that we build and serve to other solutions. The components are set for export in the index.ts file that i point to from webpack.

But when I build the project then webpack is not converting the tsx files to ts files. What am I missing ?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "@xxx/components",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": false,
  "main": "build/xxxxx",
  "types": "build/lib/index",
  "files": [
    "build"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build-lib:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack && npm run copy-css-to-lib",
    "build-lib": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack && npm run copy-css-to-lib",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s ./src/public -c .storybook",
    "build": "npm run build-lib && build-storybook",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "copy-css-to-lib": "cpx \"./src/**/*.scss\" ./build/lib",
    "prepublishOnly": "npm run build-lib",
    "lint": "eslint ./.eslintrc.js"
  },
  "repository": "xxxxx",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^8.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "^1.0.3",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.16",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/query-string": "^6.3.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.50.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^11.0.0",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.7.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.25.3",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/lib",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "types/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts"]
}
```

index.ts

```
export { MyComponent } from "./components/folder/MyComponent";
```

webpack.config.js

```
// Imports
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin = require("./IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin");
const StyleLintPlugin = require("stylelint-webpack-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer").BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const buildPath = path.join(__dirname, "./build");
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const isDev = env === "development";

console.log("Env: " + env + "|Dev: " + isDev);

module.exports = () => [
  {
    stats: { modules: false },
    devtool: "inline-source-map", //devtool: false,
    entry: {
      index: ["./src/index.ts"],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      alias: {
        react: path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react"),
        "react-dom": path.resolve(__dirname, "./node_modules/react-dom"),
      },
    },
    externals: {
      // Don't bundle react or react-dom
      react: {
        commonjs: "react",
        commonjs2: "react",
        amd: "React",
        root: "React",
      },
      "react-dom": {
        commonjs: "react-dom",
        commonjs2: "react-dom",
        amd: "ReactDOM",
        root: "ReactDOM",
      },
    },
    mode: isDev ? "development" : "production",
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "./build"),
      filename: "xxxxx.js",
      library: "xxxxxxComponents",
      libraryTarget: "umd",
      publicPath: "/build/",
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          include: /src/,
          use: "ts-loader", 
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            "css-loader",
            "resolve-url-loader",
            {
              loader: "sass-loader?sourceMap",
              options: {
                includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, "src/styles")],
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          // URL-loader to handle image resources (one URL-loader could be used for both images and fonts)
          test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
          use: "url-loader?limit=25000",
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()],
    },
    plugins: [
      new IgnoreNotFoundExportPlugin(),
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({ typescript: { checkSyntacticErrors: true, measureCompilationTime: true } }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
      new CopyPlugin({
        patterns: [
          { from: "src/public/fonts", to: "lib/fonts" },
          { from: "src/public/images", to: "lib/public/images" },
        ],
        options: {
          concurrency: 100,
        },
      }),
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
        analyzerMode: isDev ? "static" : "disabled",
        openAnalyzer: false,
      }),
    ],
  },
];
```

So when I run **npm run build-lib** I don´t get the output (ts files) from the .tsx files in the folder **MyComponent**. I point to the export in the index.ts file.